# PHPExcel Add multiple inputs into 1 cell

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I have a few entries from Mysql that I need to insert into 1 cell.

I have tried this but not working...

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G7', $row['coolingmonth'], $row['coolingweek'], $row['coolinghour']);
```

Answer (score 0):

A cell can only have one value, so concatenate them all into one string:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->SetCellValue(
        'G7', 
        $row['coolingmonth'] . 
        $row['coolingweek'] . 
        $row['coolinghour']
    );
```

Comment: Ok. I keep getting a weird output e.g. 11/01/34 ?

Comment: What are the values in $row? Do a `var_dump()` of your `$row` (debugging 101). I can only tell you how to use PHPExcel, I can't see the actual data you're putting into PHPExcel